# mongodb unwind aggregate result?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I'm trying to produce some statistics in my database using aggregation

My current script looks like this:

```
db.posts.aggregate( [
    { $group: {_id : "$domain", "counter" : {$sum : 1}}},
    { $sort : { counter : -1}},
    { $match : { counter : {$gt : 10} } }
])
```

and produces result like this:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "i.imgur.com",
            "counter" : 1220
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "imgur.com",
            "counter" : 459
        }         
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Quite satisfactory, but I want to move further. I'm using robomongo (more comfortable to me) and this appears like single document to me:

[image: screenshot]

**I want to have each result to be a separate document** like this:

```
   | _id         | counter
---+-------------+--------
 1 | i.imgur.com | 1220
---+-------------+--------
 2 | imgur.com   | 459
```

I assumed I needed to use $unwind, but failed miserably: adding `{ $unwind : "$result"}` to aggregate chain produces this output:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

What have I done wrong and how to do it right?

Comment: firstly are you getting all the results you wanted in that single array? secondly if it is a matter of formatting then its better to hand code.

Comment: A $project should do the trick. Could you provide a sample JSON object of the result?

Comment: By the way, the higher up in the pipeline that `$match` appears the better. Although there may be no real difference in performance that you'll notice with a small dataset, for best practices, it would be good to switch the order to `$group`, `$match`, `$sort`.

Comment: @AshwinBalamohan yes, here it is: http://pastebin.com/1kWp4zKY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use robomongo, but it seems like you could tack on `.result` to your script to get the results output you want.

```
db.posts.aggregate( [
    { $group: {_id : "$domain", "counter" : {$sum : 1}}},
    { $sort : { counter : -1}},
    { $match : { counter : {$gt : 10} } }
]).result
```

I've done some looking into this and it appears that the return output you are getting is a consequence of robomongo using `db.posts.runCommand("aggregate", {pipeline: [<array of pipeline operators>]})` and then not "instantiating a cursor" rather than the [`aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#aggregate-command-returns-a-cursor) helper which creates a cursor.

I don't think there's much you can do on this outside of filing a ticket.

Comment: Honestly this is the first thing I tried, but the result is single document with two fields (0 and 1), each one is an object with `_id` and `counter` fields : http://i.imgur.com/86VDbIi.png

Comment: on edit: Oh well. It's not critical for me anyway. I guess I'll open an issue on github for this problem

Comment: Oh, there are two of them already  [#507](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/507) [#522](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/522). I believe this answers my question.

Comment: @amdc and also "NoOutlet" by order that this was your response. Presently the Robomongo build is "locked in" to the MongoDB 2.4.x codebase with respect to commands and results. So `.aggregate()` cannot create a "cursor" object as it can in more recent versions of the mongo shell for example. Pretty much quoted in the issues on the codebase. But until there is V8 integration in the build and tighter build integration with the basic build, ( or an abstracting library ) it's not likely for RoboMongo to move forward on this. RoboMongo aggregation output is stuck as an array.

Comment: Interesting. I found that my [`mongo-hacker`](http://tylerbrock.github.io/mongo-hacker/) shell extension was getting the same {`result`, `ok`} output as mentioned in OP, but that getting nicer output was as simple as sending `{ cursor: {} }` in the options of `db.runCommand()` and then instantiating the cursor with `new DBCommandCursor(this._mongo, res);`